# Dynamically add form fields when option in select tag is selected

Tags: symfony

I want to add more fields in my form when I select a certain option in a select tag.

Currently i can generate the fields with a PRE_SUBMIT EventListener but i don't know how to add them just after my select tag.

I read all the documentation I could find but i didn't find the javascript code to do that.

**Select form builder :**

```
->add('place', ChoiceType::class, [
            "mapped" => false,
            "label" => "Est-ce que la structure possède un lieu ?",
            "choices" => [
                "..." => null,
                "Oui" => true,
                "Non" => false
            ]
        ])
```

**EventListener :**

```
$builder->get("place")->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $placeChoice = $event->getData();

            //si le choix est "Oui"
            if($placeChoice == 1) {
                $form->getParent()->add("theatreName", TextType::class, ["label" => "Nom du théâtre"])
                    ->add("rehearsalRoom", TextType::class, ["label" => "Salle de répétition du théâtre"])
                    ->add("administrativeRoom", TextType::class, ["label" => "Salle administrative du théâtre"])
                    ->add('postalCode', TextType::class, [
                        "label" => "Code postal du de la structure",
                        "attr" => ["maxlength" => 5]
                    ])
                    ->add("city", ChoiceType::class, [
                        "label" => "Ville de la structure",
                        "choices" => [
                            "Veuillez renseigner le code postal au préalable" => ""
                        ]
                    ]);
            }
        }
    );
```

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony give the select box a certain attribute like `data-select-hide-show` (or class, whatever you like) and all the elements that need to be hidden/shown another certain attribute like `data-hide-show-me` and a css class that hides the element to start like `hidden-class`.

```
$builder
    ->add('place', ChoiceType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'label' => 'Est-ce que la structure possède un lieu ?',
        'placeholder' => '...',
        'choices' => [
            'Oui' => 1,
            'Non' => 0
        ],
        'attr' => [
            'data-select-hide-show' => true,
        ],
    ])
    ->add('theatreName', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Nom du théâtre',
        'attr' => [
            'data-hide-show-me' => true,
            'class' => 'hidden-class',
        ],
    ])
    ->add('rehearsalRoom', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Salle de répétition du théâtre',
        'attr' => [
            'data-hide-show-me' => true,
            'class' => 'hidden-class',
        ],
    ])
    ->add('administrativeRoom', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Salle administrative du théâtre',
        'attr' => [
            'data-hide-show-me' => true,
            'class' => 'hidden-class',
        ],
    ])
    ->add('postalCode', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Code postal du de la structure',
        'attr' => [
            'maxlength' => 5,
            'data-hide-show-me' => true,
            'class' => 'hidden-class',
        ],
    ])
    ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => 'Ville de la structure',
        'choices' => [
            'Veuillez renseigner le code postal au préalable' => '',
        ],
        'attr' => [
            'data-hide-show-me' => true,
            'class' => 'hidden-class',
        ],
    ])
;
```

Javascript

```
var hideShowFields = function(selectedValue) {
    // Copy elements into an array with the "spread operator" ... so we can safely use ".forEach"
    let allElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-hide-show-me]')];
    if (parseInt(selectedValue) === 1) {
        allElements.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('hidden-class'));
    } else {
        allElements.forEach(item => item.classList.add('hidden-class'));
    }
};

// wait for page load
window.onload = function() {
    let selectElement = document.querySelector('[data-select-hide-show]');

    // Only if element exists
    if(!!selectElement) {
        selectElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
            hideShowFields(this.value);
        });

        // also trigger once on pageload
        hideShowFields(selectElement.value);
    }
};
```

Css

```
.hidden-class {
    display: none;
}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help ! Everything is working well ! 
I added the same classes and attributes to labels with "label_attr" in my form so they can be hidded or showed with inputs ! :D